# Was this email a mundane "automatic" confirmation response?

Tags: recruitment, applications

I applied to a featured international job offer last Sunday evening via StackOverflow's careers. *The next day*, before noon<sup>*</sup>, I received a reply with a slightly different subject line on my email.

The content was explaining that they received too many applications, that's why it will take them a little longer to give an answer.

Indeed, the message came from a formal email address of a HR member, where it discloses the company's address, phone and fax numbers, "think before you print" and such.

Should I be optimistic about this (e.g. my introduction made a good impression), or will everybody who applies receive the same message?

<sup>*Normally, automatic responses are right away. So, I was wondering if there were cases where automatic responses are trigger by "human intervention"?</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take what people tell you at face value.**

They told you they got a higher number of applications so it will take time to process them all. What this *really* means... is that it might take longer than you expect for them to reply because they have a high number of applicants.

They quite literally told you that they haven't even had time to read your introduction yet. The only thing you've really learned is that they'll have to cut a lot of applicants and you are unlikely to be considered if you're not an excellent match for the position.

The fact that this email came from a "real" address makes no difference. There are plenty of ways of sending mass-mails from "normal" email addresses.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I be optimistic about this

Sure, always keep a positive outlook on things like this. Worrying won't help anything except raise your blood pressure. There is no way of knowing what protocols this particular company have in place.

Answer (score 0):

An HR person hit copy and paste. But, that does mean your email made it to HR person's email account -- past any filtering software they may have. So that's cool.